# How to filter rows based on row below in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

I have data that looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(station = c("A", "A", "Bad", "A", "B", "Bad", "B", "C"),
  values = c(8.1, 3.3, NA, 9.1, 9.4, 6.5, 15.3, 7.8))

    station values
1       A    8.1
2       A    3.3
3     Bad     NA
4       A    9.1
5       B    9.4
6     Bad    6.5
7       B   15.3
8       C    7.8
```

I want to delete the rows above the rows in which the station is "Bad". I will eventually also delete the rows in which the station is "Bad" as well but I know how to do that and it is a separate question.

The output for now should look something like this:

```
output <- data.frame(station = c("A", "Bad", "A", "Bad", "B", "C"),
                 values = c(8.1, NA, 9.1, 6.5, 15.3, 7.8))

   station values
1       A    8.1
2     Bad     NA
3       A    9.1
4     Bad    6.5
5       B   15.3
6       C    7.8
```

So far I have been trying to use the dplyr filter function with variations similar to this:

```
output <- df %>% 
  filter(values != ([-1] == "Bad"))
```

I understand that the "[-1]" is not the right way to index the row above so what is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(lead(station, default = last(station)) != 'Bad')

#  station values
#1       A    8.1
#2     Bad     NA
#3       A    9.1
#4     Bad    6.5
#5       B   15.3
#6       C    7.8
```

Or in base R and `data.table` :

```
#Base R
subset(df, c(tail(station, -1) != 'Bad', TRUE))

#Data table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[shift(station, fill = last(station), type = 'lead') != 'Bad']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base `R` solution is:

```
df[-(which(df$station == "Bad") - 1),]
```

**Output**

```
  station values
1       A    8.1
3     Bad     NA
4       A    9.1
6     Bad    6.5
7       B   15.3
8       C    7.8
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
 subset(df, c(station[-1] != "Bad", TRUE))
```